# Get initial URL used to launch OS X app

Tags: swift, macos, url-scheme

I have a Mac app written in Swift with a custom URL scheme.

If the app is running and opened from a link everything works great. But if the app is not running then then the app does not open to the correct page.

I am registering for notifications like this:

```
let eventManager = NSAppleEventManager.sharedAppleEventManager()
eventManager.setEventHandler(self, andSelector: "handleGetURLEvent:replyEvent:", forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))
```

How do I get the url from the initial launch in:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)
```

Edit 1:
In my app delegate I have:

```
func handleGetURLEvent(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor?, replyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor?)
```

This function is called, and works when the app is already open, but does not work when the app is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and solved it by moving the registration call into

```
applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!

[Looking at a tutorial article you might be looking at at](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/07/30/how-to-launch-your-macios-app-with-a-custom-url/), you still need to implement a method for handling the "`kAEGetURL`" Apple Event.

In your Application Delegate, create a method that looks like this:

```
func handleGetURLEvent(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor?, replyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor?) {
    if let aeEventDescriptor = event?.paramDescriptorForKeyword(AEKeyword(keyDirectObject)) {
        if let urlStr = aeEventDescriptor.stringValue {
            let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)

            // do something with the URL
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have that function in my app delegate, but it is not triggering correctly.

Comment: where did you register your `setEventHandler`?

Comment: in the func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)